# google map apikeyごとの料金集計について

Tags: google-maps

一つのプロジェクトで複数のgoogle map apikeyを使ってサービス運用しています。

どのapikeyがどれだけ使ったのか知りたいのですが、GCPの通常のBilling画面からだと、一つのプロジェクトの合算した使用量しか表示されないので、
困っています。